# SQL - Access conditional update

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table named `POS_File_Detail`. I would like to update `Line_Number` based on the count of the `Invoice_Number` and increment by 1 for every duplicate. So basically if I have three duplicate entries with the same `Invoice_Number` it will update `Line_Number` with what duplicate number it is. Something like this

```
    Invoice_Number | Line_Number | Description
    0123456          1             Pepsi
    0123456          2             Chips
    0123499          1             Hot dogs
    0123456          3             Mustard
```

The primary key for this table is an autonumber field named Record_ID.

I'm not sure how to put this in correct syntax, but hopefully this will show you what I'm trying to do

```
    UPDATE POS_File_Detail 
    SET POS_File_Detail.Line_Number = Line_Number +1
    WHERE COUNT(Invoice_Number)>1;
```

Comment: What is the primary key of POS_File_Detail? That's a table, right (not a database as is mentioned)?

Comment: I'm completely sorry POS_File_Detail is my table not my database. The primary key is an auto increment Record_ID

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be really easy if you have a field or combination of fields which allow you to define the ordering of the duplicate Invoice_Number values.  Without such a method, the order in which those Invoice_Number values are retrieved is arbitrary.

You have an autonumber field named "Record_ID" as POS_File_Detail primary key.

```
SELECT
    Invoice_Number,
    DCount("*", "POS_File_Detail",
        "Invoice_Number = '" & [Invoice_Number] & 
        "' AND Record_ID <= " & [Record_ID]) AS Line_Number
FROM POS_File_Detail;
```

Although you asked to store Line_Number in POS_File_Detail, I gave you a SELECT statement instead.  I did that because it's *almost* always a mistake to store derived values in the table.  Better to derive Line_Number with a query whenever you need it.  That way you avoid storing redundant data and ensure Line_Number is always current despite inserts, updates and deletions to POS_File_Detail.

However **if** you have a sound reason to actually *store* Line_Number in POS_File_Detail, you can convert the SELECT to an UPDATE statement.

```
UPDATE POS_File_Detail
SET Line_Number = DCount("*", "POS_File_Detail",
    "Invoice_Number = '" & [Invoice_Number] &
    "' AND Record_ID <= " & [Record_ID]);
```

Please make sure you really have a compelling reason to store those values.

Comment: This is amazing thank you.  I have no real reason to keep the data current because it is historical transaction data out of an old IBM AS/400.  However, I will try to use the SELECT statement for good practice.  I'll let you know how it goes, thank you!

Comment: You're welcome.  I just now revised the answer to include your table name and autonumber field.  I made several typos and other errors earlier, but this looks correct to me now.  Notice I assumed Invoice_Number is text data type.  If it's not, discard the single quotes from the `DCount()` expressions.

Comment: Both of these worked perfectly, I am sticking with SELECT statement though. Thank you so much.

Answer (score -1):

```
WITH CTE(Invoice_Number,Line_Number,Description,NEW_LINE_NUMBER)
AS
(select Invoice_Number,Line_Number,Description,
ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by Invoice_Number  order by Invoice_Number) NEW_LINE_NUMBER from    POS_File_Detail)
UPDATE CTE SET Line_Number=NEW_LINE_NUMBER
```

Comment: I'll keep this in mind if I go to an actual server, thank you Nathan